# PHP: Assign null if not set?

Tags: php

Is there any sort of assign-if-not-empty-otherwise-assign-null function in PHP?

I'm looking for a cleaner alternative to the following:

```
$variable = (!empty($item)) ? $item : NULL;
```

It would also be handy if I could specify the default value; for instance, sometimes I'd like ' ' instead of NULL.

I could write my own function, but is there a native solution?

Thanks!

EDIT: It should be noted that I'm trying to avoid a notice for undefined values.

Comment: !empty($item) && ($variable = $item);

Comment: @Delta: What happens to the default value then?

Comment: @Delta That doesn't work, it won't initialize `$variable` when `$item` is empty.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

### Update

PHP 7 adds [the null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) to handle assignment depending on whether the right hand side is set.

> The null coalescing operator (??) has been added as syntactic sugar
> for the common case of needing to use a ternary in conjunction with
> isset(). It returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL;
> otherwise it returns its second operand.

```
<?php
// Fetches the value of $_GET['user'] and returns 'nobody'
// if it does not exist.
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? 'nobody';
// This is equivalent to:
$username = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : 'nobody';

// Coalescing can be chained: this will return the first
// defined value out of $_GET['user'], $_POST['user'], and
// 'nobody'.
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? $_POST['user'] ?? 'nobody';
?>
```

Additionally, PHP 7.4 adds the [null coalescing assignment operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.null-coalescing-assignment-operator), which handles the opposite case -- assigning a value depending on whether the left hand side is set:

```
<?php
$array['key'] ??= computeDefault();
// is roughly equivalent to
if (!isset($array['key'])) {
    $array['key'] = computeDefault();
}
?>
```

### Original Answer

I ended up just creating a function to solve the problem:

```
public function assignIfNotEmpty(&$item, $default)
{
    return (!empty($item)) ? $item : $default;
}
```

Note that $item is *passed by reference* to the function.

Usage example:

```
$variable = assignIfNotEmpty($item, $default);
```

Comment: These two code fragments are not equal. assignIfNotEmpty(0, $default); will return $default  while $username = 0 ?? 'nobody'; will return 0

Comment: @YourCommonSense it would probably work correctly if using `isset` instead of `empty`. [The documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) also makes reference to `isset`.

"In particular, this operator does not emit a notice or warning if the left-hand side value does not exist, just like isset()."

Answer (score 49):

*Re edit:* unfortunately, both generate notices on undefined variables. You could counter that with `@`, I guess.

In PHP 5.3 you can do this:

```
$variable = $item ?: NULL;
```

Or you can do this (as meagar says):

```
$variable = $item ? $item : NULL;
```

Otherwise no, there isn't any other way.

Comment: I didn't know that about PHP 5.3.  That certainly is cleaner!

Comment: Does this (`?:`) generates notice if undefined ?

Comment: Ish, I'd like to know this as well.  That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Ish Kumar: Unfortunately it does.

Comment: Will the second option generate a notice if undefined?

Comment: I guess `$variable = @$item ?: NULL;` would be nicer.

Answer (score 5):

There's the null coalescing assignment operator (`??=`) that can be useful if you have a nullable parameter value and want to set a default if it's null.

```
function foo(?Bar $bar): void
{
    $bar ??= new Bar();
}
```

Comment: Available on PHP 7.4+

Answer (score 2):

Well yes, there is a native solution for assigning the value or NULL when the variable was unset:

```
$variable = $possibly_unset_var;
```

If you just want to suppress the notice (which doesn't solve anything or makes the code cleaner), there is also a native syntax for that.

```
$variable = @$unset_var;
```

Comment: That's sort of a poor solution (the error suppression), don't you think?

Comment: @Peter: No, I don't think so. Notices are there for a reason, not as a pointless peeve.

Comment: It is poor. Php needs a warning-suppression operator really.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't recommend this on a production system, but:

```
<?php
//$value=1;
$item=@$value ?:null;
var_dump($item); // NULL
?>

<?php
$value=1;
$item=@$value ?:null;
var_dump($item); // 1
?>
```